# Primefaces Wizard does not proceed with selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

The wizard doesn't proceed to next tab when I use `value="#{wizard.filial.numFilial}".` But, it works fine when I use `value="#{wizard.intFilial}".` Can someone help me?

```
<!--XHTML-->
<h:selectOneMenu id="fieldFilial" title="Filial" value="#{wizard.filial.numFilial}" required="true" label="Filial*" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{commons.filiais}"  var="cfilial"
                               itemValue="#{cfilial.numFilial}" itemLabel="#{cfilial.descricao} "/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Wizard.java**

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Wizard{
        private Filial filial;
        private int intFilial;
        <GETTERS/SETTERS>
}



**Commons.java**

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Commons{
        private List<Filial> filiais;
        <GETTERS/SETTERS>
}

<!--FILIAL-->
public class Filial implements Comparable<Filial>, Serializable {
    private int numFilial;
    private String descricao;
    <GETTERS/SETTERS>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is filial getting initialized somewhere? As posted, it seems like it is not. In that case it will be null and you're essentially getting a null pointer exception when trying to access filial.numFilial (because filial is null). Does the console show anything at all? Try adding `<p:log/>` to the page; it can be useful for figuring out what is going on.

Comment: No. when I use value="#{wizard.filial.numFilial}" the method "onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event)" isn't executed, so I think it is something in the JSF life cycle. But, I can't figure out what.

Comment: Valeu Andre! It works! I thought the "JSF Life cycle" could instantiate the variable "filial" on the "Apply Request Values" phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the filial object because you need an instance of Filial type Object that contains numFilial.

Try

```
private Filial filial = new Filial();
```